# Visual Studio fetches data but not display

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer

I've read all the related answers on stackoverflow. Reportviewer never fills up.
There is data but it does not show
[image]

Comment: Could you show me your complete code to reproduce the problem to analyze?

Comment: To be honest i solved the problem using old version visul studio, when I use visual studio 2022, as you can see it brings the data to the page, I can see it in the browser too. But it doesn't show and pdf button etc is not active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Instead of updating my project, I created a new project from scratch and at this time, I saw that reportviewer was working corectly. Here is my steps;*

**For Visual Studio 2019 or 2022**

**1 -** On the top menu click Extensions-->Manage extensions -->
Search "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer" or "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022"
Download and install "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer" and restart Visual Studio

**2 -** Add Report.rdlc files to the project
with using Manage nuget packages,
Search Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms and Install

**3 -** In toolbox, under "Microsoft Sql Server" you can see ReportViewer
(If you can not see click anywher in toolbox and select choose items and add ReportViewer)

**4 -** Create a new aspx file
Drag ReportViewer control to this aspx file and add your rdlc file

**5 -** When you open your page in browser you will see the report.

Comment: Hi yusuf hayırsever, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: You could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It's under the polls.